# Failure sending mail in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, exception, smtpclient

I developed a site for sending mail. This is my method:

```
public string sendMail() {
    try {
        result = "Message Sent Successfully..!!";
        string senderID = "mymailid@gmail.com";
        const string senderPassword = "mypassword";
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderID,senderPassword),
            Timeout = 30000,
        };
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(senderID, txtToEmail.Text, 
        txtSubject.Text, txtBody.Text);
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        result = ex.Message;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The detailed exception is:

> Unable to connect to the remote server.

I tried using Gmail and Outlook. Both gives same exception. When I change to port 25, it shows connection timed out

Comment: Sounds more like a Proxy/firewall issue than the code itself.

Comment: how to solve that???

Comment: Without having any form of insight into your situation, make sure that outbound traffic on port 25 or 587 is allowed from where the application is running.It has nothing to do with programming, but rather your network infrastructure.

Comment: Turn off your firewall.

Comment: Tried but no use...